# pass data between components in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to add a dashboard component and try pass user details to it. I declare in dashboard.component.ts user: User, which has his own model and in ng on it i declared it as:

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data['user'];
    });
```

now when i call in in html as {{user.firstName}} i get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (DashboardTopbarComponent.html:213)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:36090)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35073)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35361)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35074)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35361)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35074)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
```

This is my dashboard.component.ts file

```
export class DashboardTopbarComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data['user'];
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember, that `js` is a single threaded language. Even if you subscribed to the `data` and as a callback pass a function which will set your `user`, the user will be set only after `Angular` finish rendering your component, so you are trying to get field `firstName`, while your object is null/undefined. What you should do, is grab the `user` from `snapshot` and then subsribe to `data` (yes, it will be called twice but you will be handling case when user changes somehow), or wrap your template with `ngIf`.

Comment: I created a resolver and add it to routes. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize user in controller

```
user:User = {}
```

or you should check if user is exist in HTML file, try this

```
{{user && user.firstName}}
```

Comment: I tried to use first option and i get this error error TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, username, firstName, lastName, and 9 more.

Comment: All the props in your props interface User are required, so change  = {}  by = {username:"", firstName: ""} ...etc